# Compare array with match for multilines in python

Tags: python

I am trying to compare all values with each other, example:

```
Array 1 -> Line1 == Array2 -> All lines
```

But this way I am comparing as follows:

```
Array 1 -> Line 1 == Array 2 -> Line 1
```

I tried to use the `zip()` function, but it turns the values of array2 into only one value

**SCRIPT**

```
# concate dict values result
for array1 in outputsocks:
    for array2 in resultcmdb:
        m = re.compile(r'^('+array1+')', re.MULTILINE)
        results = m.search(array2, re.MULTILINE)
        print(results)
```

**INPUT**

```
outputsocks = ['srv1.fqdn.domain.com','srv2.domain.com','srv3.domain.com']
resultcmdb = ['srv3','srv2','srv1.fqdn']
```

**OUTPUT**

```
None
Match
None
```

Comment: Could you provide a small test input and output so I can understand your problem better?

Comment: yes, i edit post!

Comment: done! @BrianBarbieri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using:

```
import re

outputsocks = ['srv1.fqdn.domain.com','srv2.domain.com','srv3.domain.com']
resultcmdb = ['srv3','srv2','srv1.fqdn']

[re.match(r"^({})".format(item), item2) for item, item2 in zip(resultcmdb,outputsocks)]
```

Output:

```
[None, <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='srv2'>, None]
```

Comment: How to print the value instead of none?

Comment: @LuisHenrique The value that was matched for? like "srv3" ?

Comment: I say print what did not match, the gaps

Comment: for example if there was a srv4

Comment: Something like: `[re.match(r"^({})".format(item), item2) if re.match(r"^({})".format(item), item2) else item for item, item2 in zip(resultcmdb,outputsocks)]`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to match each index? If that is true, this should do:

```
outputsocks = ['srv1.fqdn.domain.com','srv2.domain.com','srv3.domain.com']
resultcmdb = ['srv3','srv2','srv1.fqdn']

for sock, cmdb in zip(outputsocks, resultcmdb):
    if cmdb in sock:
        print("Match")
    else:
        print("No match")
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly, the problem is that my array2 loses all values when using zip (), this is very strange

Comment: What is happening before this part of the program? That should be the part where array2 loses its values.

Comment: Array 2 is just an array populated by a DB data table, in this pattern ['value1', 'value2']